# Jboss 6.1 DV integration with IBM Mainframe

Tags: jboss, virtualization, mainframe

Does Jboss 6.1 Data Virtualization beta provides integration with Mainframe using RACF protocol authorization ? I searched thru the internet and couldn't get any detail procedure.

Answer (score 1):

RACF is what is known in the mainframe world as an External Security Manager (ESM).  There exist other ESMs such as ACF2 and Top Secret.  Other products such as CICS and DB2 communicate with the resident ESM for authentication and authorization purposes.

You don't communicate with the ESM, you communicate with (for example) DB2 supplying your authentication credentials and DB2 asks the ESM to authenticate you.

I am not a JBoss person, but I think you want to read Chapter 3 in the [Security Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Virtualization/6.1/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#About_Authentication1).